# Mapbox - Style property according to zoom and property

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I'd like to style points on my map as follows:

```
'circle-radius': {
  property: 'pixelRadius',
  stops: [
    [0, 0],
    [20, 'pixelRadius'],
  ],
  base: 2,
}
```

The use case is similar to [Drawing a circle with the radius in miles/meters with Mapbox GL JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599561/drawing-a-circle-with-the-radius-in-miles-meters-with-mapbox-gl-js)

Except that in my `properties` map I have computed the pixel radius so that each point in the FeatureCollection has its own radius.

Can this be done? All of the examples Ive seen with `stops` have a hard coded value for the 2nd array element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'circle-radius': [
    "interpolate",
    ["exponential", 2],
    ["zoom"],
    0, 0,
    20, ['get', 'pixelRadius']
],
```

So here it is using expression (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-get) instead of function.