# How to draw the circle in the mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I've searched how to draw the circle in the mapbox using Javascript but couldn't find out the correct solution.

```
var myCircle = new MapboxCircle({lat: data.lat, lng: data.lng}, data.radius, {
    editable: true,
    minRadius: data.minRadius,
    fillColor: data.color
}).addTo(map);
```

The above code is provided by Mapbox but it allows just add the circle Layer in fixed radius on the map.

But what I wanted is to draw the circle in dynamic radius by dragging.

Comment: Do you want to draw the circle dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass these radii in meters using the latest version of Leaflet. The radius will change relative to zoom levels.

Here's some more information via **Leaflet's documentation**

```
L.circle([lat,lng], radius).addTo(map);
```

More documentation here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.9/l-circlemarker/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In the mapbox, there is a similar function, but the thing what I want is draw the circle, not just add the layer on the map.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: please check this link work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599561/drawing-a-circle-with-the-radius-in-miles-meters-with-mapbox-gl-js/37601549#37601549

Comment: Wow, that's what I want. Thanks.