# Draw a circle in a fixed area on the mapbox map. || Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, dictionary, geometry, mapbox, geofence

I've created an app I've used geofence I want. Show a circle on the mapbox with the same radius as the geofence. The problem is that the circle is displayed and the size of the circle changes as the map is zoomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want a proper circle feature.  Rather, you want a polygon with many vertices that resembles a circle.  This has been answered already with ready-to-use code here: [Drawing a circle with the radius in miles/meters with Mapbox GL JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599561/drawing-a-circle-with-the-radius-in-miles-meters-with-mapbox-gl-js/39006388#39006388)